# Busy on SELECT in SQLite with multiple connections

Tags: sqlite

In my (test) application I have *multiple threads* where each thread makes *multiple `SELECT` calls one after another*. Each thread has its *own connection* to the (same) SQLite database.

Everything works fine for a couple of calls but then I start getting `SQLITE_BUSY` errors ("database is locked") back from `sqlite3_step()`.

I know I can circumvent this with `sqlite3_busy_timeout()` but I want to know why this is happening or whether this is expected behavior.

Please note that I'm *only doing read operations* (unless `SELECT` is considered a write operation nowadays), so SQLite should only acquire a shared lock, shouldn't it?

I'm on Windows (7 x64) and running SQLite 3.7.13.

Comment: Are you using shared cache mode and/or WAL?

Comment: Ehhh... I don't know. I haven't explicitly enabled any of this.

Comment: Did you change the [`SQLITE_THREADSAFE`](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#threadsafe) compilation option? Are you using [`sqlite3_config()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/config.html)? Are you using [`SQLITE_OPEN_*MUTEX`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_open_autoproxy.html) flags in [`sqlite3_open_v2()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html)?

Comment: Yes, shared lock but it will block if someone else have exclusive lock.